# How to get pronunciation phonemes corresponding to a word using C#?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, microsoft-speech-api

I'll preface this by saying I'm very novice when it comes to C# programming. I'm working on an application for programmatically modifying the Windows Speech Dictionary using C# in conjunction with SAPI v5.4 ([speechlib](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125663(v=vs.85).aspx)). Everything is working well so far but I need to gain more insight about how strings are interpreted when they are synthesized (voiced).

My understanding is that in SAPI 5.4 words are broken down into [phoneme representations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431828(v=vs.85).aspx), and I had some success getting word pronunciations to be "trained" correctly using the phonemes. I also know I can add words manually to the Windows Speech Recognition dictionary, provide a voice recording, and then extract the word's pronunciation (phonemes)...but this is cumbersome. It would also be useful to explore how the words are synthesized by default, i.e. without input from me (like how does the synthesizer interpret "dolphins"?).

From a coding point of view here's what I've got so far:

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace SpeechTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set up the speech synthesizer
            SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            synthesizer.Volume = 100;
            synthesizer.Rate = -2;

            // Configure the audio output 
            synthesizer.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

            // Initialize string to store word of interest (not in the speech dictionary)
            string myWord = "dolphins";

            // Speak the word of interest
            synthesizer.Speak(myWord);

            // Retrieve pronunciation of myWord
            string myPronunciation = // *some code here*

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the amazing work of [Casey Chesnut](http://www.mperfect.net/speechSamples/) I've figured out how to determine the IPA phones for a given string. Now I just have to figure out how to convert from IPA phones to SAPI symbols, but that's for a separate topic (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824781/how-to-recognize-voice-events-using-spinprocrecocontext-in-c) for how to get the SAPI phonemes from a text string).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SpeechTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string MyText = "dolphins"; // Initialze string for storing word (or words) of interest
            string MyPronunciation = GetPronunciationFromText(MyText.Trim()); // Get IPA pronunciations of MyTe
            MessageBox.Show(MyText + " = " + MyPronunciation); // Output MyText and MyPronunciation
        }

        public static string recoPhonemes;

        public static string GetPronunciationFromText(string MyWord)
        {
            //this is a trick to figure out phonemes used by synthesis engine

            //txt to wav
            using (MemoryStream audioStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
                {
                    synth.SetOutputToWaveStream(audioStream);
                    PromptBuilder pb = new PromptBuilder();
                    //pb.AppendBreak(PromptBreak.ExtraSmall); //'e' wont be recognized if this is large, or non-existent?
                    //synth.Speak(pb);
                    synth.Speak(MyWord);
                    //synth.Speak(pb);
                    synth.SetOutputToNull();
                    audioStream.Position = 0;

                    //now wav to txt (for reco phonemes)
                    recoPhonemes = String.Empty;
                    GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder(MyWord);
                    Grammar g = new Grammar(gb); //TODO the hard letters to recognize are 'g' and 'e'
                    SpeechRecognitionEngine reco = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
                    reco.SpeechHypothesized += new EventHandler<SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs>(reco_SpeechHypothesized);
                    reco.SpeechRecognitionRejected += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs>(reco_SpeechRecognitionRejected);
                    reco.UnloadAllGrammars(); //only use the one word grammar
                    reco.LoadGrammar(g);
                    reco.SetInputToWaveStream(audioStream);
                    RecognitionResult rr = reco.Recognize();
                    reco.SetInputToNull();
                    if (rr != null)
                    {
                        recoPhonemes = StringFromWordArray(rr.Words, WordType.Pronunciation);
                    }
                    //txtRecoPho.Text = recoPhonemes;
                    return recoPhonemes;
                }
            }
        }

        public static string StringFromWordArray(ReadOnlyCollection<RecognizedWordUnit> words, WordType type)
        {
            string text = "";
            foreach (RecognizedWordUnit word in words)
            {
                string wordText = "";
                if (type == WordType.Text || type == WordType.Normalized)
                {
                    wordText = word.Text;
                }
                else if (type == WordType.Lexical)
                {
                    wordText = word.LexicalForm;
                }
                else if (type == WordType.Pronunciation)
                {
                    wordText = word.Pronunciation;
                    //MessageBox.Show(word.LexicalForm);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(String.Format("[0}: is not a valid input", type));
                }
                //Use display attribute

                if ((word.DisplayAttributes & DisplayAttributes.OneTrailingSpace) != 0)
                {
                    wordText += " ";
                }
                if ((word.DisplayAttributes & DisplayAttributes.TwoTrailingSpaces) != 0)
                {
                    wordText += "  ";
                }
                if ((word.DisplayAttributes & DisplayAttributes.ConsumeLeadingSpaces) != 0)
                {
                    wordText = wordText.TrimStart();
                }
                if ((word.DisplayAttributes & DisplayAttributes.ZeroTrailingSpaces) != 0)
                {
                    wordText = wordText.TrimEnd();
                }

                text += wordText;

            }
            return text;
        }

        public static void reco_SpeechHypothesized(object sender, SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs e)
        {
            recoPhonemes = StringFromWordArray(e.Result.Words, WordType.Pronunciation);
        }

        public static void reco_SpeechRecognitionRejected(object sender, SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs e)
        {
            recoPhonemes = StringFromWordArray(e.Result.Words, WordType.Pronunciation);
        }

    }

    public enum WordType
    {
        Text,
        Normalized = Text,
        Lexical,
        Pronunciation
    }
}

// Credit for method of retrieving IPA pronunciation from a string goes to Casey Chesnut (http://www.mperfect.net/speechSamples/)
```